# Twitter issues in old project

Tags: android, twitter

Yesterday I got one old project when i am trying to compile the project i get following error

Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix in

```
 <activity android:name="net.mxxxx.xxxxx.twitter.AuthTwitter" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data host="twitterAuth" android:scheme="xxxxxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Minimum SDK was "7" i made it up to 13 , Please help why error is occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question is why it wasn't complaining before. Just change this:

```
<data host="twitterAuth" android:scheme="xxxxxx" />
```

to

```
<data android:host="twitterAuth" android:scheme="xxxxxx" />
```

Comment: Thanks it works now , I just got the code , i dont know about previous version.